# iTunes sync podcasts

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization

Is there a way to sync iTunes podcast subscriptions across two iTunes installations; one on a Mac and the other on a W7 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the list of subscriptions between them, but I don’t know how to keep them in sync.

1. In the sidebar of the first iTunes installation, select `Podcasts`, right click, then click `Export`. I use the OPML file type, but others might work. (Let’s call it `Podcasts.opml`).
2. Using a USB stick, Dropbox, or some other method, transfer `Podcasts.opml` to the computer with the second iTunes installation.
3. Select `File` > `Add to Library`, and find `Podcasts.opml`. Once you open it, your second iTunes installation will have the same podcast subscriptions as the first.

Two comments:

- This won’t keep them in sync; if your podcast subscriptions change, you’ll need to repeat the above to carry the changes across.
- There may well be a much easier method, using something like Home Sharing or Dropbox, to keep the single library file synced between the two machines.